# How does Node JS know how to handle routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just trying to get a partial page to load.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-pp='app' lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Friends</title>
    <script src='angular/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='angular-route/angular-route.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a href='#!/list'>All Your Frinds</a> | <a href='#!/new'>Add a Friend</a>
    </p>
    <div ng-view=''>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Routing:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider)
     {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/list', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'
        })
        .when('/new',
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/create.html'
        })
        .when('/show/:id',
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/show.html'
        })
        .when('/edit/:id',
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html'
        })
        .otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: '/'
        })

    });
```

Although, I have a controller, there is nothing in it.  I just want to be all to see the a partial page is loading and it is not.  I need the ng-controller directive in my partial page for it to load?

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with Node.JS.

Comment: What error are you getting? Check your console.

Comment: given that code, angularjs is the one who will handle routes. Not Node

Comment: The proper question would be 'Angular no work.' https://codepen.io/CarterTsai/pen/vHtbK  Most times, you can google codepen and find an example of whatever angularjs thing you need to see an example of.

Answer (score 1):

**It doesn't do anything in this example**

Most likely your nodejs is serving your static angularjs content from a folder, if you are using expressjs it will be because of

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

However, the angularjs router is handling your partials

Make sure you set

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

It can also help by looking into the developer console to see what url your router is pointing too.

Also 
  is fine by itself without the ""

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code after removing exclamation mark from href and it's working as expected. Also add base href in HTML. Try below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-pp='app' lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <base href="/"></base>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Friends</title>
    <script src='angular/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='angular-route/angular-route.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a href='#/list'>All Your Frinds</a> | <a href='#/new'>Add a Friend</a>
    </p>
    <div ng-view=''>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider)
 {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/list', 
    {
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'
    })
    .when('/new',
    {
        templateUrl: 'partials/create.html'
    })
    .when('/show/:id',
    {
        templateUrl: 'partials/show.html'
    })
    .when('/edit/:id',
    {
        templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html'
    })
    .otherwise(
    {
        redirectTo: '/'
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The directive was misspelled... Should be:

```
ng-app
```